# Bash: identifying which command printed which output

Tags: linux, bash, named-pipes

I want to write a program that works as follow:

- The user runs my program, and I, on behalf of the user, run a `bash` process (for example, through `ssh`)
- Everything the user enters, is sent to the stdin of the `bash` session, and everything the process prints, is captured by my program.
- Everything written to the bash's `stdout` by everything spawned by a same line, go to a same file.

My current (untested) approach is:

- If the user wrote the line `line`, I replace it by three lines as follow:

```
exec >$unique_named_pipe 2>&1
line
exec >/dev/fd/1 2>/dev/fd/2 # Restore the original stdout and stderr ???
```

- That, as I understand, will make everything spawned by `line` inherit the fd table from the parent process, which use the named pipe instead of the terminal for `stdout` and `stderr`.
- If `line` contains manual redirections, my named pipes are ignored. That's a good thing.
- Finally, a daemon prints everything written to any of the named pipes to the `stdout` of the `bash` session itself, together with some distinctive mark to allow my process to distinguish lines.
- My process opens a log file per-line. For example, the fifth line uses `5.log` as associated file. The process then writes to each corresponding file the output of its correspoding line by parsing the added marks.
- No `line` will send ever anything directly to `stdout` or `stderr`, only my daemon and `bash` itself will

There's some things that I haven't figure it out yet:

- Imagine that `line` is a 5-minute running command on the foreground. During these 5-minutes, the line won't sent any output to my program. However, where is the daemon sending messages to? If the `bash` session has redirected its `stdout` to the named pipe, and the daemon is sending output to the session's `stdout`, would the daemon write everything to the named pipe? How can I make sure the daemon is sending messages to my program (e.g, the "original" `stdout` of the `bash` session before the redirection to the named pipe happened).
- If the user close my program, I have to remove all the named pipes and finish the bash session, but, what would happen with background commands sent with `nohup`? Will they fail just after removing the named pipes but before closing the `bash` session?
- I need to know whenever a line has completed its execution including any background process launched by it (imagine a line such as `command1 &; command2 &;`). I need this to:

  - Close the named pipe.
  - Notify my program to close the associated file (by printing a special message to the `stdout`).
- Is there any important "danger" I'm not considering here? (besides interactive commands like top or vi).

Comment: It sounds like you are re-inventing [tag:expect]

Comment: `exec >/dev/fd/1 2>/dev/fd/2` won't work. Since the fd's were redirected by the previous `exec`, `/dev/fd/X` refers to the redirected location, not the original binding of those fd's. You need to save the the original destinations in new fd's, then restore those.

Comment: `exec 3>&1 4>&2 >$pipe 2>&1` before, and `exec >&3 2>&4 3>&- 4>&-` after.

Comment: There isn't really any robust way to tell when the output of a command has finished. Most programs that try to do this look for something that looks like a shell prompt. But since prompts can be customized, they have to have a very general pattern and sometimes can be fooled.

Comment: @glennjackman if I understood well, `expect` is its own interpreter who doesn't understand bash, and I want that it works with bash.

Comment: @Barmar what if 3 and 4 are fds in use?

Comment: @ABu there is a shell-oriented implementation called [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) -- here's [an example script](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/blob/master/examples/ssh.sh). There is also an example to "Start multiple jobs in parallel and monitor each job's output until all done"

Comment: @ABu You can use the syntax `{variable}>&1`. This will find an unused FD, duplicate to that, and assign `$variable` with the ID.

Comment: @Barmar If I know that, before the change, `&1` and `&2` points to the same open file description, wouldn't suffice to do: `exec {FD1}>&1 >$pipe 2>&1` before, and `exec >$FD1 2>&1 $FD1>&-` after? Or is it wrong?

Comment: That's exactly right